# Sencha touch Error: Uncaught Error The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'Ext.data.model'

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

"Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'Ext.data.model'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'touch/src/data/model.js "

I am getting this error which I have no idea why is being generated. Here is my code have a look because i have turned every stone But still no answer. It seems every tiem i write a code few hours goes to figuring out what is wrong with sencha touch

App.js

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'TutsPlus': 'app'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
    //http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application
    name: 'TP',

    views: ['Main'],
    models: ['mtask'],
    stores: ['stask'],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('TP.view.Main'));
    }

});
```

In Store stask.js

```
    Ext.define('TP.store.stask', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        //Define which model we are going to use for our store
        model: 'TP.model.mtask',
        data: [
            {label: 'Make the change'},
            {label: 'Take the trash'},
            {label: 'Clear the room'},
            {label: 'Wake Up Early'}
        ]

    }
});
```

In Model mtask.js

```
Ext.define('TP.model.mtask', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {

        fields: [
            {name: 'label', type: 'string'},
            {nae: 'done', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false}
        ]
    }

});
```

In view folder Main,js

```
Ext.define('TP.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.dataview.List'
    ],

    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtpe: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Note Taker',
                items: [
                    {
                        iconCls: 'add',
                        iconMask: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        id: 'add-button'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: 'stask'





            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: `Ext.data.*M*odel`. Case matters.

Comment: I actually wrote Ext.data.Model as you can see inseide model folder and also i tried with lower case but it does't work.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your model class is not getting declared. Try finding out the reason with syntax errors and cases.
 Try changing:

**nae: 'done'** to **name: 'done'**